# how to get rid of the zero in time

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm working on my python script to get the current time.

When I have the current time between `01:00PM` and `09:00PM`, the code will removed the `0` so it will show `1:00PM` and `9:00PM`.

When my time show between `01:00AM` and `09:00AM`, it won't remove the `0`.

Used this code:

```
# Set the date and time row
current_time = time.time() # now (in seconds)
half_hour = current_time + 60*30  # now + 30 minutes
one_hour = current_time + 60*60  # now + 60 minutes

for t in [current_time,half_hour,one_hour]:
    if (0 <= datetime.datetime.now().minute <= 29):
       self.getControl(4204).setLabel(time.strftime("%I").lstrip('0') + ':00' + 
time.strftime("%p"))
       self.getControl(4205).setLabel(time.strftime("%I").lstrip('0') + ':30' + 
time.strftime("%p"))
       self.getControl(4206).setLabel(time.strftime("%I" + ":00%p",time.localtime(t)))
    else:
       self.getControl(4204).setLabel(time.strftime("%I").lstrip('0') + ':30' + 
time.strftime("%p"))
       self.getControl(4205).setLabel(time.strftime("%I" + ":00%p",time.localtime(t)))
       self.getControl(4206).setLabel(time.strftime("%I" + ":30%p",time.localtime(t)))
```

I have no idea how to remove the `0` for the AM.

Can you please tell me how I could remove the `0` for the AM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why aren't you `lstrip`ing for every piece of time?

```
>>> "01:00AM".lstrip("0")
'1:00AM'
>>> "09:00PM".lstrip("0")
'9:00PM'
```

This line doesn't have `lstrip`:

```
self.getControl(4206).setLabel(time.strftime("%I" + ":00%p",time.localtime(t)))
```

How to add it:

```
self.getControl(4206).setLabel(time.strftime("%I" + ":00%p",time.localtime(t)).lstrip("0"))
```

Comment: Ah, the reason I used this code `self.getControl(4206).setLabel(lstrip(time.strftime("%I" + ":00%p",time.localtime(t))))` is because I'm adding the hour to one hour forward. I tried to add the `lstrip` but i will get an error to something like this: `NameError: global name 'lstrip' is not defined` when I'm using this code: `self.getControl(4206).setLabel(lstrip(time.strftime("%I" + ":00%p",time.localtime(t))))`. Do you know why I got an error?

Comment: Thank you very much for this, I can see it have fixed the issued. Problem solved! (Y)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do such complicated acrobatics:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> t = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> t.hour
17
```

`.hour` will give you the 24-hour value. Simply check if this is between 13 and 21 and then format your string accordingly.

To get the half-hour and full hour:

```
>>> t
datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 18, 17, 58, 35, 98698)
>>> t + datetime.timedelta(minutes=30)
datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 18, 18, 28, 35, 98698)
>>> t + datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 18, 18, 58, 35, 98698)
```